# С# Таймер и backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms

Не работает код:

```
protected System.Timers.Timer timer; 
public Loading()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!timer.Enabled)
    {
        Main mf = new Main();
        mf.Show();
        Hide();
    }
}
```

Ожидается, что текущее окно будет показано как минимум три секунды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна просто пауза в 3 секунды? Тогда вам совершенно не нужен ни Timer, ни BackgroundWorker.

Проще всего сделать так (для WPF):

```
public Loading()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var dt = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) };
    dt.Tick += (sender, args) => { dt.Stop(); Close(); };
    dt.Start();
}
```

Для WinForms есть свой таймер: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, который предпочтительнее, чем `System.Timers.Timer`. Для них практически так же:

```
public Loading()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var t = new Timer() { Interval = 3000 };
    t.Tick += (sender, args) => { t.Stop(); t.Dispose(); Hide(); };
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: А для Winforms?

Comment: @МатвейКотцов: Дописал.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно задействовать встроенное событие Elapsed класса Timer. и передать этому событию ссылку на ваш метод обработчик "backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted"

```
protected System.Timers.Timer timer; 
public Loading()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    /* Подключаем событие Elapsed со ссылкой на метод ckgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted которое повторяется через каждые 3 сек.*/
    timer.Elapsed += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
Console.WriteLine("Нажмите кнопку Enter для выхода из программы... ");
}
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!timer.Enabled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Произошло событие Elapsed время:  {0}", e.SignalTime);
        Main mf = new Main();
        mf.Show();
        Hide();
    }
}
```